# Android Studio Emulator Crashing on windows Obsolete and has serious performance problems

Tags: java, android-studio

I just started coding and I am playing around with Android Studio. However, everytime I am trying to run the emulator I have this message of error (click on the picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ22F.png)

How can I fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just opened Android SDK Manager Then it showed 4 Updates Available. So I just Updated it and No more above warning.

[image]